# Include files inside zip file

Tags: php, zip

Is it possible to include files inside zip file?

I tried this:

```
$za = new ZipArchive(); 

$za->open('test.zip'); 

for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){ 
    $stat = $za->statIndex( $i );
    if($stat['size']!=0){
        echo $stat['name'];

        include("./".$stat['name']."");
        $a=file_get_contents($stat['name']);
        echo $a;
    }
}
```

The idea is to use zip as folder and inside I'd have some files in php with information. And the idea is to include all using `include` function. I don't know if it's possible but I need this or some way to get it. Also if it's possible modificate inside of zip the file I want with some functions, the sale I can do with fput, fopen, etc.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ro/ziparchive.addfile.php

Comment: I don´t want add , i want include file inside of zip file in other file of php , the same when we include for example config.php but in this case config.php it´s inside of zip file , regards